why does Quartus Prime shows a path as failing in case of CDC even though synchronizers are used?
suppose a signal is coming from a slower to a faster clock domain, and 2 levels of synchronizing FFs have been used, then the tool shows failing path from the launch node to the first synchronizing capture FF.
What happens in such cases if I use set_false_path constraint? Does this constraint say that because synchronizers are used here, do not evaluate this path?

Exactly. It tries to evaluate the phase relationship between latch and launch clock, fails, and marks the path as failing.
set_false_path removes the path from consideration, which is fine here because there is a synchronizer.

How to make the software detect synchronizer and not flag the path as failing? I have seen a setting for synchronizer detection but not for the later.

You specify it as a false path. That's why that function exists.

Can you suggest how will the PnR result vary for the PnR run where I did use the set_false_path and the run where I did not use the above constraint?

Quartus uses timing driven PnR -- so timing constraints affect initial placement, optimization, and of course in the final verification run it affects pass/fail.

Will the two nodes with failed path be placed as near as possible and will both of them be placed farther away when the set_false_path constraint is applied?

Since you have a synchronizer and a false path, the distance no longer matters, because a long delay only means that the data arrives one cycle later if it is right on the edge. So, the path before the first FF now has lower priority during optimization, leaving more resources for the others, so in principle this should improve.
